# Is tabu search a learning algorithm? (CVRP)

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, operations-research

I've been set the assignment of producing a solution for the capacitated vehicle routing problem using any algorithm that learns. From my brief search of the literature, tabu search variants seem to be the most successful. Can they be classed as learning algorithms though or are they just variants on local search?

Answer (score 0):

Search methods are not "learning". Learning, in cotenxt of computer science is a term for learning machines - which improve their quality over training (experience). Metaheuristics, which simply search through some space do not "learn", they simply browse all possible solutions (in heuristically guided manner) in order to optimize some function. In other words - optimization techniques are used to train some models, but these optimizers themselves don't "learn". Although this is purely linguistic manner, but I would distinguish between methods that learns - in the sense - are trying to generalize knowledge from some set of examples, from algorithms which simply are searching for best parameters for arbitrary given function. The core idea of machine learning (which distinguishes it from optimization itself) is that the aim is to actually maximize the quality of our model on **unknown** data, while in optimization (and in particular tabu search) we are simply looking for the best quality on **exactly known, and well defined** data (function).